# android call two function in onclick

Tags: android

I'm trying to call two functions in the same `onClick` event. When I click the `Button` just one function is called and the second is called for the second time I click the `Button`.

```
btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        promptSpeechInput();
        String result =  txtSpeechInput.getText().toString();// Wrong emplacement // TODO: 23/04/2017
        if (result.equals("call")) {
            call("number");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: put your whole code here...

Comment: Then I guess result doesnt equal "call". Be aware that this is case sensitive, if you don´t care about capital and small letters, you should use `equalsIgnoreCase()`....

Comment: what you are doing in promptSpeechInput(),may be  first time your condition is not satisfying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are opening a speech `Dialog`, and at that time your `If` condition is also called but condition is not satisfying, so your other function is not called.
Put the below code in `onActivityResult()`.

```
   String result =  txtSpeechInput.getText().toString();
    if (result.equals("call")) {

        call("number");
    }
```

Ref: http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-speech-to-text-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the app in debug mode to figure out the issue. But what I can understand from the code is that

promptSpeechInput();

the method is the method that may prompt a user to speech and then extracts the text out of it. So surely it would be doing all this processing on a different thread and therefore it would take some time to return some value while your main thread just starts the promptSpeechInput(); methods and moves to the next statement where txtSpeechInput.getText().toString(); has not still got any text so making your If condition false and not calling your function.

If what I am thinking is true then u need to call this code:-

String result =  txtSpeechInput.getText().toString();
        if (result.equals("call")) {

```
        call("number");
    }
```

in the call back of speech recognition. It should be supporting that can't tell how without knowing how it works.

Debugging the code will verify the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Possible reason is because when your Onclick function get call, 1st `promptSpeechInput()` get execute and possible your code in that method was is not yet ended and your expecting to call both the function at same time. But nextfunction will only get execute once your 1stfunction get executed completely.

I would suggest just debug in `promptSpeechInput()` method and triage what makes your code to be on hold.

Comment: thanks .. i put the second fonction in activityresulrt and it's work